One 3 ph transformer rating versus the rating of 3 single ph transformers for the same load?
If I have a single load on a 3 phase system drop at 480 V and 200 A what would be the suggested rating of 3 individual line transformers on the drop? What would be the rating of a single 3 phase transformer on the same drop for the same single load? 480 V x 200 A x 1.732 / 1,000 = 166.3 kVA minimum required for one 3 phase transformer.
Presuming the load is balanced on the system, i.e. each line it seems ideally the kVA rating of the individual transformers could be a third of the total load. Is the standard practice to presume you don't lose more than one leg in most outages and so the total rating is divided in half to size the single line transformers or are they all sized for the full load rating?

TLH, What do you mean by "drop"? Maybe it's a translation thing?

Probably a Southwest slang that is used when we want to hook up a new load on an existing distribution line it's not uncommon to ask them for a new "drop" on their system.  Instead of saying "they will be Installing new transformers and a meter..." we refer to is as they are "dropping in a new delivery point for us on their system".
